# can't see the alert here. What could the reason be?

Tags: javascript, jquery, zend-framework

```
function votar(eid){
    alert('inside function');
    $.post(baseUrl+"/index/voto",{id:eid},function(e){
            alert('after post');
```

I have this function here. On developer server, I get all working. No problems.
Once I upload to the production server I got only the first alert to show.

```
$.post(baseUrl+"/index/voto",{id:eid},function(e){
```

The baseUrl is correct.

The /index/voto is the correct path (the same as dev. server) to the voto method into index controller, id:edid is a json format yes, so, nothing wrong, and at the end, I just have that callback.

What possibilities do we have for the fact that the second alert is not showing on the production environment ?

Later on this same file, I have this function, the the same line of code, and it works perfectly:

```
function showDetails(eid, elemento){
  $.post(baseUrl+"/index/details.campaign",{id:eid},function(e){
```

The only difference being the server side function it calls, "details.campaign" on one side, "voto" on the other.

Could we state that the issue must rely there, and only there ?

Update:
Here is, ipsis verbis, the full votar function:

```
function votar(eid) {
    $.post(baseUrl+"/index/voto",{id:eid},function(e){
        var divMsg = $("#msg");
        var colunasFinalistas = $("#colunasFinalistas");
        var rodape = $("#rodape");
        var botaoVota = $("#votaEmGrande");
        var html = "";

    //no caso de votar pela primeira vez
    if(e.msg == 1){
        html = '<img src="'+baseUrl+'/lib/img/obrigadoParticipacao.png" alt="pdf" />';
                        rodape.removeClass("margemSeparadorRodape");
                        colunasFinalistas.hide();
        }else if(e.msg == 3){
            //no caso ja ter votado - se não existir nenhum elemento já:
                        if ($('#votoJaContabilizado').length == 0) {
                            botaoVota.after('<p id="votoJaContabilizado">O teu voto já foi contabilizado.</p>');
                        }
        } else if(e.msg == 2){
            //no caso da equipa nao existir
            html = '<img src="'+baseUrl+'/lib/img/equipaNaoExiste.png" alt="pdf" />';
                        colunasFinalistas.hide();
        } else{
            //no caso de outro erro
            html = '<img src="'+baseUrl+'/lib/img/erroEstranho.png" alt="pdf" />';
        }


                if (html != ''){
                    divMsg.html(html);
                    divMsg.show();
                }



    }, 'json');

}
```

Comment: Is `baseUrl` on the same domain? You're probably running into cross-domain issues; the call is not allowed, so the success callback is not executing. Use Firebug to debug further.

Comment: @MEM, "Could we state that the issue must rely there, and only there" - why? If you're just looking to point fingers, this is the wrong site. If you want to know what's actually going wrong, you should get to the debugga. :)

Comment: I don't agree with the close vote - because it sure could help others because, it sure could happen to others that for some no apparent reason a similar issue arrive, and we must understand where to look at on those cases. Should we look on the client side, should we look on the server side. I would love to someone to tell me exactly where the problem is but, not being possible, at least to understand, on those cases, or similar ones, where should I look at. That will help enough.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: The baseUrl must not be the issue, because, the other function showDetails uses baseUrl with no issues.

Comment: @MEM: .. which was posted after I wrote my comment.

Comment: @MEM: This is not a "how do I debug my code" website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, and tell us what you get:

```
var vote = $.post(baseUrl+"/index/voto",{id:eid},function(e){
    alert('after post');
});
vote.error(function(e){
    alert(e.statusText);
});
```

Comment: I will, thank you. :/ I'm deploying this right now... and I'm nervous... :s

Comment: Take it easy, don't stress out. Whatever is to happen, will happen... You are gonna make it. :)

Comment: @Shef: I got an alert telling me 'after post'; - :s

Comment: @MEM: Your post request is going through well then! Now do whatever you want to do with it. It is posting OK and you get an alert from within the POST`s success function. The only thing I can think of, which might be causing your problem is if you didn't close the parentheses. Please post your whole function so we can debug your problem.

Comment: @Shef: I've just added the full version. I will, on the next minutes, to try out to right something after that alert based on your code.

Comment: If I try your code I get the alert. if, I place the all code inside, I don't get the alert (nor the other), IF, I copy paste your code, and, at the end of $.post I add json, like this: `function votar(eid){
var vote = $.post(baseUrl+"/index/voto",{id:eid},function(e)
{
    alert('after post');
    
    }, 'json');
vote.error(function(e){
    alert(e.statusText);
});
}` I got no alert. (not sure if this helps)

Comment: Hmm... Your JS function [works just fine](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/WWrY9/). Check to make sure your `(baseUrl+"/index/voto"` echos `Zend_Json::encode()`ed code.

Comment: @Shef: on the server side ? Ok. And I will look to the other working function that is doing almost the same, but working.

Comment: Yes, check to make sure you encode everything you return to the request as valid `JSON`. In your case you can use `Zend_Json::encode()` to do that, or whatever you are using for the other request.

Comment: I'm having two different versions of that line. The version that IS working:  `return $this->_helper->json($arr[$idEquipa]);` and the version that seems to not be working: `return $this->_helper->json(array("msg"=>$msg));` - they have their differences, but, perhaps, on one version I cannot declare an array at the same time json is called or something. I will try to upload all zend framework files.

Comment: For the second one, change all that line to this: `$myMsg = json_encode(array("msg"=>$msg)); return $this->_helper->json($myMsg);`

Comment: @Shef: It was a Server Side issue. Another user have upload to the dev server a file that I didn't had on my local pc. So when I upload, I was never uploading that necessary file. Thanks a lot for your help because, indeed we need dialectic on those things. :) Thank you again and again!

Answer (score 2):

At the risk of stating the obvious, if the callback method is not being called, it means the call was not successful.

$.post is a shorthand for the full $.ajax. Try using $.ajax and implement a function for error; this will show you if any errors are being thrown which your code is missing.

More information on $.ajax here: [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url:  baseUrl+"/index/voto",
    data: //any required params go here,
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        debugger;//hooray it worked!
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        debugger;//there was an error
    },
    dataType: //type of data you are expecting back from the server
});
```

Comment: I have another function on this file that as, exactly the same structure (see update), and that one works perfectly.

Comment: @MEM yes (seen the update now) but it is not the same call - therefore there are numerous reasons why it would fail. My approach would be to get as much information as possible: add a callback for when it errors or perhaps monitor the server to see if the request is received and/or any response returned.

Comment: @globsrob: Thank you really. Please: On data we should place the server side voto() method required params - is that it ?

About dataType: are we talking about things like string, number and so on?

Comment: @MEM the post below is probably an easier approach to get any error information but for completeness: the datatype is the type of data you are expecting the server to return: from memory the supported types are JSON, XML, Script and HTML. The data would be '{id:'+eid+'}'

Comment: @globsrob: thanks a lot. It will sure help me a lot on future issues like this. :)

Answer (score 1):

The third parameter in the `$.post` function is the **success** callback. So if it is working fine on developer server and not your production server, you got an issue with the response you are getting from the server. Have you had a look at what the response if from the server, because your ajax request isn't getting a success.

Inspect the response you are getting from your server (if any) and/or check if anything is done on the server when the `$.post` is submitted.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the request is failing in your development server. First, I would suggest showing the baseUrl in the first alert so you are sure the address is ok. If the address seems ok, set a function to handle the error with $.ajaxSetup or $.ajaxError before doing your $.post call

```
$.ajaxError(error: function (event, jqXHR, ajaxSettings, thrownError){
  //try to find out the error
});
```

More into on $.ajaxError [here](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/).

Also, you can try using [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to examine the request from your server

Comment: Not sure how to debug. Should I wrap that function around $.post ?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get back to you, but I saw that you resolved the issue with someone else's help. Glad it all worked out.